# Install Ubuntu Desktop on ARM tablet like Aquaris

Tags: tablet, arm

I have an Aquaris M10, and I was wondering if there is a way to install Ubuntu Desktop to it.  I've been mostly disappointed by Ubuntu Touch in the way it locks down the OS.  Sure it look like Ubuntu, but very little of what I was expecting is actually there, or even planned.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is it possible to install Ubuntu (14 or later) on this little ARM tablet?
2. Would this ruin my ability to put Touch back on it in the future?

I'm mostly looking to use java and server-related applications on it, so I'm not too worried about not having the whole Ubuntu Software Center available to an ARM system.

Answer (score 0):

Installing ubuntu natively is not possible due to hardware limitations, but you should take a look at the **Debian Noroot** app or the **Linux Deploy + BusyBox + some vnc app** combination. (I recommend bVNC)

You can read many further options here: http://www.androidauthority.com/install-ubuntu-on-your-android-smartphone-765408/